# Importar funciones de una subcarpeta para un proyecto Python

Tags: python, python-import

estoy haciendo un programa en Python y la verdad es que soy bastante novato y estoy teniendo problemas con los imports.

Estructura de datos:

[image: estructura de datos:]

El caso es que DumpAnalyzer.py ejecuta la funcion Menu() del archivo OptMenu, que a su vez llama a SwitcherClass y este a FuncIP.

En ultima instancia, al intentar ejecutar el programa me dice que SwitcherClass no existe;

> Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "DumpAnalyzer.py", line 2, in                                                                                import Scripts.OptMenu                                                                                                File "D:\Utiles\Scripts\OptMenu.py", line 2, in                                                                   from SwitcherClass import Switcher                                                                                  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SwitcherClass'

Entiendo que debo haber hecho mal con los imports, los copio:

DumpAnalyzer:

```
import sys
import Scripts.OptMenu

Scripts.OptMenu.menu()
```

OptMenu:

```
import sys
from SwitcherClass import Switcher
```

SwitcherClass:

```
import FuncIP
```

Espero no haberlo hecho demasiado lioso, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero has un `__init__.py` en el folder Scripts, esto facilita que python los pueda encontrar y si estas usando python 3

```
import sys
from .SwitcherClass import Switcher
```